# Maven install failed in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Maven installation in CMD successful whereas Eclipse failed, have tired maven update, clean and install.I am using same JDK, Maven and Setting.XML file in CMD and in Eclipse

Eclipse error follows

```
   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
     [WARNING] 
     [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.anz.authentic:authentic-anz-product:jar:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT
     [WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.type' for com.google.gwt:gwt:jar must be 'pom' to import the managed dependencies. @ com.anz.authentic:authentic-anz:${revision}, C:\NotBackedUp\authentic\authentic\pom.xml, line 3783, column 26
     [WARNING] 
     [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.anz.authentic:authentic-anz-package:pom:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT
     [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ com.anz.authentic:authentic-anz-package:${revision}, C:\NotBackedUp\authentic\authentic\authentic-anz-package\pom.xml, line 1218, column 15
     [WARNING] 
     [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.anz.authentic:authentic-anz:pom:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT
     [WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.type' for com.google.gwt:gwt:jar must be 'pom' to import the managed dependencies. @ com.anz.authentic:authentic-anz:${revision}, C:\NotBackedUp\authentic\authentic\pom.xml, line 3783, column 26
     [WARNING] 
     [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
     [WARNING] 
     [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
     [WARNING] 
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
     [INFO] 
     [INFO] authentic-anz                                                      [pom]
     [INFO] authentic-anz-product                                              [jar]
     [INFO] authentic-anz-extension                                            [jar]
     [INFO] authentic-anz-product-nr                                           [jar]
     [INFO] authentic-anz-package                                              [pom]
     [INFO] 
     [INFO] ------------------< com.anz.authentic:authentic-anz >-------------------
     [INFO] Building authentic-anz 0.9.1-SNAPSHOT                              [1/5]
     [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
     [INFO] 
     [INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.5:revision (get-the-git-infos) @ authentic-anz ---
     [INFO] 
     [INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.1.0:flatten (flatten) @ authentic-anz ---
     [INFO] Generating flattened POM of project com.anz.authentic:authentic-anz:pom:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT...
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Reactor Summary for authentic-anz 0.9.1-SNAPSHOT:
     [INFO] 
     [INFO] authentic-anz ...................................... FAILURE [  3.248 s]
     [INFO] authentic-anz-product .............................. SKIPPED
     [INFO] authentic-anz-extension ............................ SKIPPED
     [INFO] authentic-anz-product-nr ........................... SKIPPED
     [INFO] authentic-anz-package .............................. SKIPPED
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Total time:  3.446 s
     [INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-05T10:41:48+05:30
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:flatten-maven-plugin:1.1.0:flatten (flatten) on project authentic-anz: 206 problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.anz.authentic:authentic-anz:${revision}
     [ERROR] [WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.type' for com.google.gwt:gwt:jar must be 'pom' to import the managed dependencies. @ 
     [ERROR] [ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${authentic.root.groupid}.product:authentic-account-card-import:jar with value '${authentic.root.groupid}.product' does not match a valid id pattern. @ 
     [ERROR] [ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${authentic.root.groupid}.product:authentic-atm:jar with value '${authentic.root.groupid}.product' does not match a valid id pattern. @ 
     [ERROR] [ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${authentic.root.groupid}.simulator:authentic-atm-simulator:jar with value '${authentic.root.groupid}.simulator' does not match a valid id pattern. @ 
     [ERROR] [ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${authentic.root.groupid}.product:authentic-atm-ui:jar with value '${authentic.root.groupid}.product' does not match a valid id pattern. @ 
     [ERROR] [ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${authentic.root.groupid}.product:authentic-authorisation-ui:jar with value '${authentic.root.groupid}.product' does not match a valid id pattern. @
```

Comment: what does your `pom.xml` look like?

Comment: First problem: `com.google.gwt:gwt:jar must be 'pom' to import the managed dependencies. @ `. Second problem: `[ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${authentic.root.groupid}.product:authentic-account-card-import:jar with value '${authentic.root.groupid}.product' does not match a valid id pattern. @`. please show a full pom file...

Comment: https://github.com/jayesh2527/new-project/blob/master/pom.xml